# Reload Pulse (under insights) data on github repository

Tags: git, github

Used an alt account while working on a uni project on github. Realized that after having made the push from my computer. Changed commit history to show the correct author. Checked commit history on github, alt name nowhere to be seen; however, in pulse (under the insights section) the name is still present (it says that the alt account made a couple commits). Is there a way to reload the pulse statistics to show the reflected change in the git history? Thanks!